# Spl, ArrayObject, ArrayObject::STD_PROP_LIST

Tags: php, spl, arrayobject

I'm trying to understand STD_PROP_LIST constant in the documentation but so far i didn´t understand it, and didn´t found any explanation :(
The documentation has the following example:

```
$a = new ArrayObject(array(), ArrayObject::STD_PROP_LIST);
$a['arr'] = 'array data';                             
$a->prop = 'prop data';                               
$b = new ArrayObject();                                   
$b['arr'] = 'array data';                             
$b->prop = 'prop data';                               

// ArrayObject Object                                     
// (                                                      
//      [prop] => prop data                               
// )                                                      
print_r($a);                                              

// ArrayObject Object                                     
// (                                                      
//      [arr] => array data                               
// )                                                      
print_r($b);
```

Both prints give me the same exact result:

```
ArrayObject Object ( [prop] => prop data [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array ( [arr] =>      array data ) ) 
ArrayObject Object ( [prop] => prop data [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array ( [arr] => array data ) )
```

Anyone could help me understanding what is the difference between using this constant or not?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 100, accepted):

The `ArrayObject` and `ArrayIterator` are 2 classes that are really similar. They actually both share lot of code internally inside the php core. These two classes have a internal array to store the elements you set to those classes.

The `STD_PROP_LIST` tells us how to read, and `ARRAY_AS_PROPS` tells us how we to write those elements. First of all,setting elements through the standard array (`[]`) notation will always work the same way, regardless of these settings.

When setting `ARRAY_AS_PROPS` flags, it means that when you set properties (through the `->`), will not be set on the object like you would expect with regular objects, but will be stored as internal elements. If this flag is NOT set, it will store the property onto the actual array-object or array-iterator, which is what you see in the code output from your example: the "`prop => propdata`" is not inside the `storage:ArrayObject:private`, which would have been the case if the `ARRAY_AS_PROPS` flag would have been set:

```
$a = new ArrayObject();
$a['arr'] = 'array data';
$a->prop = 'prop data';

$b = new ArrayObject(array(), ArrayObject::ARRAY_AS_PROPS);
$b['arr'] = 'array data';
$b->prop = 'prop data';

print_r($a);
print_r($b);

// Output:
ArrayObject Object
(
    [prop] => prop data
    [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
        (
            [arr] => array data
        )
)
ArrayObject Object
(
    [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
        (
            [arr] => array data
            [prop] => prop data
        )
)
```

The `STD_PROP_LIST` decides on what to return on certain conditions, most notably at `var_dump()`. Though there will be other cases, i haven't found them myself. If the `STD_PROP_LIST` is set, it will return the properties that have been set onto your `ArrayObject`, or `ArrayIterator` class. If it's NOT set, then `var_dump()` will return a list of the internal elements that have been stored.

The actual documentation is not 100% correct on `STD_PROP_LIST`. This flag affects `var_dump()`, but not `foreach()`. When using `foreach()`, it will always iterate the internal elements, and never the actual properties, even when `STD_PROP_LIST` has been set.

These two flags are not mutually exclusive: you can set both flags, but it wouldn't make much sense doing so: it means that properties are always added as internal elements (`ARRAY_AS_PROPS`), and we want to return the standard properties through `var_dump` (`STD_PROP_LIST`). Since properties cannot have been set, it will always return an empty list in that case.

Comment: You should put this answer in the PHP docs comments because it clarifies a lot about the ArrayObject flags. I didn't find this kind of explanation even in the docs. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is so confusing, yet it's the best explanation I've found.

Answer (score 1):

A great answer by @JayTaph but `print_r` is more like a debug function. To actually use the arrays in for instance a `foreach` it becomes clear that the both differ significantly:

```
$a = new ArrayObject();
$a['arr'] = 'array data';
$a->prop = 'prop data';

$b = new ArrayObject(array(), ArrayObject::ARRAY_AS_PROPS);
$b['arr'] = 'array data';
$b->prop = 'prop data';

echo "\$a:<br>\n";
foreach( $a as $key=> $value) {
  printf( "[%s] : %s<br>\n", $key, $value);
}

echo "\$b:<br>\n";
foreach ($b as $key => $value) {
  printf("[%s] : %s<br>\n", $key, $value);
}
```

will output:

```
$a:
[arr] : array data
$b:
[arr] : array data
[prop] : prop data
```