# PHPUnit: I want to create a mock object that 'is' an array. Not returns an array

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

So I don't know if anyone has asked this but...

For unit testing, I want to create a mock object that behaves like an array. Not returns an array. I can't just use an array, because the array needs to be of type 'test'.

So somehow...I want the mocked type test object to be set as array('blah', 'blah');

The reason I want to do this is because I am passing the object into a type 'test' restricted parameter of another object.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an **[ArrayObject](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php)**.

`class Test extends ArrayObject` or build a Mock class which extends ArrayObject.

This gives you an object of type test with array functionality.

When you use ArrayObject::STD_PROP_LIST you can work with it, like with an normal array.

```
$a = new Test(array(), ArrayObject::STD_PROP_LIST);
$a['blah'] = 'blah';
```

See here for STD_PROP_LIST example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16619183/1163786